# jquery sorter controls disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a jquery tablesorter that has asp buttons inside. When the asp buttons are clicked the jquery controls disappear. I need to refresh the page the for them to reappear. Any suggestions on the tablesorter to ignore the asp onclick?

Thanks!

Comment: You should add some code in order to make your question easier to solve. You should also read the [How to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to create a well construct and answerable question

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding an event.stopPropagation() and it solved my issue.